Gremlingo stuck while evaluting g.V().hasNext()
I have a piece of code where i evaluate to drop vertices but only if a pre-fetch of
g.V().<filters>.hasNext() returns true.
Problem is on my subsequent call to fetch the nodes themselves it is getting stuck for some reason.
hasNext, err := g.V().<filter>.hasNext()

if err != nil {
  return err 
}

if hasNext {

   // Program is stuck here
   ids, err := g.V().<filter>.Id().ToList()
   ....
}




Can you provide more context on what you mean by "stuck"?  Is it possible that the query has a large set of data to return?  You can always check the status of running queries via: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-api-status.html

Its stuck at evaluating the query. I'm running tinkerpop server locally and observe the following exceptions. Works with small amount of data

TinkerGraph on Gremlin Server is meant more for experimentation and as a reference implementation for building a TinkerPop compliant storage backend.  If you're looking to do anything at-scale, you're better off trying to use a product or service that implements TinkerPop (https://tinkerpop.apache.org/providers.html)

I found out what was causing this to be stuck indefinitely.
It looks like the go version of gremlingo has a weird implementation of HasNext(). Instead of adding it as a strategy it fetches the complete results, and then returns if the results are non-empty, which in my opinion is not helpful at all when checking for any results.
Error:
https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-go/driver/traversal.go#L99
This seems to wait until receiving a signal on the waitChannel externally.
https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-go/driver/resultSet.go#L107
There doesnt seem to be a way to signal this to stop.
Python:
The python version of the gremlin library and im sure other versions as well, use this function as a strategy.
https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/927/files#diff-bf65a33ee80dbc36f03915459a68114aa5d2fb54217588f18832e23be29822dcR77
Workaround:
I needed a lightweight query to tell me if there are more results in my query criteria and i used this instead of the HasNext()
res, err := g.V().<filters>.Limit(1).ToList()

if len(res) == 0 {
   // no more results
} else {
  // results available
}





Use GraphTraversal.TimeLimit(...) to make it unstuck:
   ids, err :=  g.V().<filter>.Id().TimeLimit(...).ToList()

